# Pension or Property: Should I invest in more properties, or in a pension?

Tags: united-kingdom, pension, investing, real-estate

I do not have a pension but have a rental property (which breaks even).  Question is, do I invest in more properties or take out a pension ?

I am worried if I go down the pension route I would lose all if there is another down turn.

Comment: How old are you – or if you'd prefer not to answer that directly, how many years until you want to retire? Since the question is about a pension, this is key to providing a good answer.

Also: a pension is a wrapper within which you can hold many different kinds of assets. Would it be right to infer from your question that you have in mind an off-the-shelf fund-managed pension where a manager conservatively invests your money in shares and bonds?

Comment: Is a pension in this case similar to an investment portfolio (for US-based viewers)?

Answer (score 9):

Diversification is one aspect to this question, and [Dr Fred touches on](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/290/36669) its relationship to risk.  Another aspect is leverage:

- If you put money into pension it's unleveraged, that is you invest £50,000, and make 10%.  You have £55,000.
- Another rental property is likely to be leveraged.  You put in £50,000, and borrow £150,000 to buy a £200,000 property.  If the market rises 10% you make £20,000 so have £70,000.  On the flipside if the market drops 10% you lose £20,000.

So it again comes down to your appetite for risk.  A further factor is that if you are successfully renting out your property, someone else is effectively buying that asset for you, or at least paying the interest on the mortgage.

Just bear in mind that if you get into a situation where you have 10 properties and the rent on them all falls at the same time as the property market crashes (sound familiar?) then you can be left on the hook for a lot of interest payments and your assets may not cover your liabilities.

Answer (score 8):

Investing in property hoping that it will gain value is usually foolish; real estate increases about 3% a year in the long run.  Investing in property to rent is labor-intensive; you have to deal with tenants, and also have to take care of repairs.  It's essentially getting a second job.

I don't know what the word pension implies in Europe; in America, it's an employer-funded retirement plan separate from personally funded retirement.  I'd invest in personally funded retirement well before buying real estate to rent, and diversify my money in that retirement plan widely if I was within 10-20 years of retirement.

Comment: A pension in the UK is just money you receive in retirement. It may be from the government (the state pension), an employer (a company pension) or personal retirement savings (a personal pension).

Answer (score 5):

I think the real answer to your question here is **diversification**.  You have some fear of having your money in the market, and rightfully so, having all your money in one stock, or even one type of mutual fund *is* risky as all get out, and you could lose a lot of your money in such a stock-market based undiversified investment.

However, the same logic works in your rental property.  If you lose your tennant, and are unable to find a new one right away, or if you have some very rare problem that insurance doesn't cover, your property could become very much not a "break even" investment very quickly.

In reality, there isn't any single investment you can make that has no risk.  Your assets need to be balanced between many different market-investments, that includes bonds, US stocks, European stocks, cash, etc.  Also investing in mutual funds instead of individual stocks greatly reduces your risk.

Another thing to consider is the benefits of paying down debt.  While investments have a risk of not performing, if you pay off a loan with interest payments, you *definitely* will save the money you would have paid in interest.

To be specific, I'd recommend the following plan -

1. Pay off any consumer debt you have
2. Use half of your extra income to pay down your rental property
3. Put the other half of your extra income toward diversified market investments.